# Encoding error with accents. Spring-mvc when summit form

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have an app with spring framework. I have a form, I submited the form with jQuery:

```
console.log( jQuery("#descripcionCuenta").val() );
jQuery("#cuentaDeCobroForm").submit();
```

I recived this from in the next method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/emitirCuentaDeCobro", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST} )
public String emitirCuentaDeCobro(
        @ModelAttribute("cuentaDeCobroDominio") CuentaDeCobroGUIDTO cuentaDeCobroGUIDTO,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap,
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    ....
}
```

When the field has accents (á, é, í...) the field descripcionCuenta in the console is ok, but in the method don't show correctly, show ? instead of the accents.

Ex:

Descripción:
In console: Descripción 
In the method: Descripci?n

Any idea how to solve this?

I tried add a filter in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and modified the connector in server.xml:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" ...>
    ...
</Connector>
```

and these don't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in web.xml

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
        <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why? A good answer on Stack Overflow comes with a little explanation, not just a chunk of code. Thanks for taking the time to post an answer and welcome!